# postman leer json desde pre script?

Tags: json

Tengo una peticion pero esta peticion devuelve respuestas de error diferentes de acuerdo al cuerpo del body, neseciro que postman me lea un archivo json y por cada body request me haga un peticion y catar la informacion de cada request, pero todo desde un codigo javascript ya que necito hacer lo mismo con otros endpoint y ejecutarlos al tiempo.
no he encontrado mucha informacion de como hacerlo. de antemano si me pueden ayudar les estare muy agradecido.